# How to convert date as.POSIXct?

Tags: r, date

I'm trying to convert dates using as.POSIXct

```
dates <- c("1-DEC-2011 00:56:06.82", "1-DEC-2011 01:29:57.07", "1-DEC-2011 01:49:05.37",
"1-DEC-2011 01:50:04.97", "1-DEC-2011 01:54:44.53", "1-DEC-2011 01:55:03.10"
)
as.POSIXct(dates, tz="", format="%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

This produces a vector of NA:s. How this conversion on is done?

Comment: I tried to reproduce this, and couldn't: the exact code from your question worked as expected (using R 2.10.1).

Comment: I would if the problem has to do with your current locale (so that `%b` doesn't work as expected).

Comment: I'm using R 2.14.0, maybe you should upgrade?

Comment: Why should *I* upgrade, if everything is working as expected here?! ;-)

Comment: There are some features that you might find interesting (parallel processing support, compiler for R code). But if these do not interest you, staying at R 2.10 can work (although I'd recommend upgrading a little faster).

Comment: @jrara, the code works fine for me, I'm using R 2.14.1 under Fedora Linux (13).

Comment: Works for me. 2.14.1, Slovenian locale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English") 

#put your timezone
```

and run your code again.

Comment: Yes, the reason was my locale, thaks!